# Is there a way to have Excel VBA send data to a socket?

Tags: excel, sockets, vba

I have an excel file which is refreshing data every few seconds and running calculations on the data. I would like to be able to send it to various clients via a socket, is this possible? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803329/light-client-using-windows-socket-and-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I think that it's possible, I wouldn't advise it.  Excel isn't setup for that and it's highly likely that it won't be completely stable, even on a server.

You might want to investigate using SQL Server Express or another database solution that can operate it in the background and should provide that functionality.

Maybe if you give some details on what you're trying to provide, you will get a better selection of options.